# SpringBoot Test ERROR ( Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(Entity) )

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, junit

Hello i write and backend service that sells flight tickets and i'm trying to write tests for this api. When i try to write createAirlineCompany test for AirlineCompanyController class i get this error.

```
Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(flight.flightticketapp.entities.AirlineCompany)'
```

My test class:

```
@Test
    public void testCreateAirlineCompany()
    {
        AirlineCompany airlineCompanyNew = new AirlineCompany();
        airlineCompanyNew.setName("RYANAIR");
        when(airlineCompanyService.createAirlineCompany(airlineCompanyNew.getName())).thenReturn(airlineCompanyNew);
        ResponseEntity<AirlineCompany> airlineCompanyResponseEntity = testRestTemplate.postForEntity
                (ROOT_URL+"/airlinecompany/airlineCreate",airlineCompanyNew,AirlineCompany.class);
        AirlineCompany airline = (AirlineCompany) airlineCompanyResponseEntity.getBody();
        assertNotNull(airlineCompanyResponseEntity.getBody());
        assertEquals(airlineCompanyNew.getName(),airline.getName());

    }
}
```

and my AirlineCompanyService class:

```
@Service
public class AirlineCompanyManager implements AirlineCompanyService {
@Override
    public Result createAirlineCompany(String name) {
        return airlineCompanyAbstract.createAirlineCompany(name);
    }
}
```

My AirlineCompany Imp class:

```
@Component
public class AirlineCompanyImp implements AirlineCompanyAbstract {
  @Override
    public Result createAirlineCompany(String name) {
        AirlineCompany airlineCompany = new AirlineCompany();
        airlineCompany.setName(name);
        add(airlineCompany);
        return new SuccessResult(Messages.airlineCompanyCreated);
    }

@Override
    public Result add(AirlineCompany airlineCompany) {

        airlineCompanyRepository.save(airlineCompany);
        return new SuccessResult(Messages.airlineCompanyAdded);
    }

}
```

The error i got is coming from thenReturn() method and i don't know how to fix this. Thank you for all.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have imported correct **static methods when()**

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
```

Comment: i made sure it's correct one

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch of the return value you use for the mock.
When specifying the mock you return an `AirlineCompany`:

```
 when(airlineCompanyService.createAirlineCompany(airlineCompanyNew.getName())).thenReturn(airlineCompanyNew);
```

But your AirlineCompanyService returns a `Result`:

```
public Result createAirlineCompany(String name)
```

Mockito searches for a method returning an `AirlineCompany` - which does not exist. You have to return a `Result` from your mock, e. g.

```
when(airlineCompanyService.createAirlineCompany(airlineCompanyNew.getName())).thenReturn(new Result());
```

Comment: But when i try to do what u said i get this error:

`org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.`

Comment: I guess your test class is annotated by `@SpringBootTest` or `@WebMvcTest` and you're injecting an `@Autowired` bean for `airlineCompanyService`?
If so you have to inject a so called "mocked bean" for using it with Mockito. This is done by injecting the bean with `@MockBean` instead of `@Autowired`.